# primality test speed

Tags: prime-numbers, primality-test

Noticed using a lattice with line $x+y=n$ for n prime, every grid point on the line is co-prime. For example:

[image: Lattice with x+y=n]

To test, I wrote a C program to specify a number (e.g., 104729) then travels along the line looking for a non co-prime point (x,y) and outputs prime or not prime:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

unsigned int gcd(unsigned int a, unsigned int b) {
    unsigned int t;
    while (b != 0) {
        t = a;       
        a = b;       
        b = t % b;    
    }
    return a;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv)
{
    // x+y=n
    unsigned int x, y, n;

    // This number is prime:
    n = 104729;

    for (x = 1; x < n; x++)
    {
        y = n - x;
        if (gcd(x, y) != 1)
        {
            printf("Not Prime: %u\n", n);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (x == n)
    {
        printf("Prime: %u\n", n);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to speed up the prime check using some fancy maths tricks.

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect this test is much slower than trial division.

Comment: Your current algorithm will run in $O(n \log n)$ time if $n$ is a prime (the $\log $ comes from $\mathsf{gcd}$), while you can decide primality in $O(n^{1/2})$ time in the worst case. Indeed, if $n$ is not prime, then its smallest divisor larger than $1$, must not exceed $n^{1/2}$, since if $d$ divides $n$ then $n/d$ also divides $n$, thus both cannot become larger than $n^{1/2}$. Thus, all you need is to check the numbers from $2...[n^{1/2}] + 1 $ to see if any of them divides $n$. If none of them does, then $n$ is prime, otherwise you have non prime.

Comment: Nice explanation...Thanks!

Comment: It should be mentioned that trial division is NOT the fastest known algorithm to test primality, even if we want to prove the primality, we can do much better. With trial division  alone, even the fastest computers would only be able to find rather small prime numbers.